# Am I right with this Double Hashing?

Tags: algorithm, hashtable, double-hashing

I am learning about Double Hash and I got difficulties understanding how it works. I have done an example but I don't know whether it's right or wrong. It would be great if someone can help me.
This is the input:

---

m = 13

---

k = { 5, 14, 29, 25, 17, 21, 18, 32, 20, 9, 15, 27 }

---

h1(k) = k mod 13

---

h2(k) = 1 + (k mod 11)

[image: My result]

Answer (score 3):

That will work as long as `m` is prime.

Otherwise `h2(x)` could evaluate to a [non-relative-prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers) of `m`, which could make the algorithm fail when there is still room for more items.

For example:

- `m = 36`
- `h1(x) = 1`
- `h2(x) = 30`
- If `table[1]`, `table[31]`, `table[19]`, `table[13]`, `table[7]` are all used; Then the next slot that will be checked is `table[1]` again.

If `h2(x)` is relatively prime to `m`, the cycle will always visit all slots before returning to the starting-point. If `m` is prime, all numbers will be relatively prime.